# Best way to embed Tumblr as your blog

Tags: javascript, dns, embed, blogs, tumblr

I have a domain (lets say www.domain.com) and I want one section of that to link to a tumblr blog (lets say www.domain.com/blog.php) I've seen the javascript option in Tumblr for embedding blogs and also tinkered with the API, but essentially, I need the blog to cover the following bases:

- Search engines must see my website and the tumblr account as the same
  entity, so any SEO benefits of the blog are given to my site rather
  than the tumblr account.
- It must be seamless for users. It must appear that everything is
  in the same site.
- All features of tumblr (such as navigation and pagination) must be
  present on the blog, not just the latest post.

It appears there are two ways of doing this; I can either create a page on my site that pulls in my tumblr feed, or forward that page on my site to my tumblr account (which would be skinned up to look identical to my site).

Which way would achieve all of the points outlined above? It if is the latter, would I need to change any DNS settings for my website?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd see better results by pulling the content into your page. Any reasonable search engine will know it's been forwarded.

You should look into tumblr plugins for your blog software. For example, Wordpress has a [Tumblr Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tumblr-widget-for-wordpress/).

Comment: My website will be a simple portfolio, not built on a CMS. I just wanted to have one section of my site as a blog, without having to forward to Tumblr.

How will search engines know not to index the tumblr blog independently from my website if if is just being pulled into the site?

Comment: I don't think Tumblr is really all the SEO friendly. You'll have more control over it on your own site and be able to better optimize it for SEO.

Comment: Surely if it is the exact same content, then search engines will give both sites (the tumbr blog and the content pulled into my site) the same preference?

Comment: Not necessarily. Take a look at [this article](http://danzambonini.com/tumblr-seo-and-why-i-moved-to-wordpress/) for some of the SEO problems with tumbler. Some of those you would have better control over on your own site. Overall I'm not sure I'd be hoping tumblr would be the key to my search rankings.

Comment: Thanks for the great advice, I think I'll go down the wordpress route!

Answer (score 1):

All of those will end up with duplicated content for Google. I would create a subdomain blog.myurl.com using Tumblr custom domain name http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains.
This way you have myurl.com with your site and blog.myurl.com for tumblr.

Comment: But wouldnt myurl.com and blog.myurl.com be seen as separate websites? And would adding myurl.com/blog.php as the custom domain name have the same effect?

Comment: The problem is that I don't believe Tumblr will let you add myurl.com/blog.php as custom domain. I believe a subdomain is your best option, no duplicated content.